# php fwrite and fopen in same statement

Tags: php, io

I saw a php script that wrote to a file like this:

`fwrite(fopen($logFileName, "a"), $logData);`

That is definitely more succint than:

```
$handle = fopen($logFileName, "a");
fwrite($handle, $logData);
fclose($handle);
```

Especially for one-liners, or when you want to write to a file in a single statement.

Is it ok not to use `fclose` on the first approach? or is that code considered buggy in a way?

Bonus question: is there a one-liner similar to `file_put_contents($logFileName, $logData)` but that allows me to append to a file instead of overwritting it?

Thanks :-)

Comment: [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) has an append flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main mistake in this one-liner is the missing fclose.
Not a good style at all.

However, if this is the only statement or the programmer doesn't care about some open file handles within the script-lifetime, that might be ok.

Caution: Normally, php cleans up any resources allocated during runtime when a script terminates. This is especially true for CGI-calls. I guess, this is also true for non-CGI-calls (php module hosted within the webserver), but you should be aware of that.

And for your bonus question: 
The answer is yes, although i guess you wanted something different.

```php
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($filename).$newContent);
```

Literally, your question has been answered here, semantically, this is not even worth a try because you read the whole file into memory just to put it back again.

But, what prevents you from writing that function on your own?

```php
function file_put_additional_contents( $filename, $content ){
   $file = fopen($filename, "a");
   fwrite($file, $content);
   fclose($file);
}
```

[edit]
As Symeon Quimby pointed out, there is a special flag for file_put_contents:

```php
file_put_contents($filename, $content, FILE_APPEND);
```